# Calendar with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar, tikz-calendar

I borrowed the following code from [here](https://teatimeandlayout.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/creare-un-calendario-con-latex-iii/) and made changes according to my requirements. I want to show year at each corner of the border and would like to know how to change the year to custom year. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

**Output**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=4.9mm, multi={tikzpicture}]{standalone}
%\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,tmargin=4.5cm,centering,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%%in preamble:
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calendar}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\newcommand{\calrow}[1]{\node[anchor=base east](Mon){M};
\node[base right=of Mon](Tue){T}; \node[base right=of Tue](Wed){W};
\node[base right=of Wed](Thu){T}; \node[base right=of Thu](Fri){F};
\node[base right=of Fri](Sat){S}; \node[base right=of Sat](Sun){S};
\node[darkgreen,above=of Thu]{\textbf{#1}};}

\newcommand{\calperiod}[1]{\calendar[dates=\the\year-#1-01 to \the\year-#1-last]
if(Sunday) [black!50] \holidays;}

\newcommand{\holidays}{% holidays in Italy
if (equals=01-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=01-06) [black!50]%
if (equals=04-04) [black!50]%
if (equals=04-05) [black!50]%
if (equals=04-25) [black!50]%
if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=06-02) [black!50]%
if (equals=08-15) [black!50]%
if (equals=11-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=12-08) [black!50]%
if (equals=12-25) [black!50]%
if (equals=12-26) [black!50]%
}

\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}

\begin{document}
%%in document:
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list}]
\sffamily
\matrix[%
row 1/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},%
row 3/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
row 5/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
row 7/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
column sep=1ex,%
draw=darkgreen,thick,rounded corners=5pt,%
postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.51 with
{\node[fill=white,text=darkgreen,font={\bfseries\Large}] (year) {\the\year};}}}
% year on frame: decorations.markings library
]{%

% first row: week day and month
\calrow{January} & \calrow{February} & \calrow{March} \\
\calperiod{01} & \calperiod{02} & \calperiod{03} \\[1ex]

% second row: calendar
\calrow{April} & \calrow{May} & \calrow{June} \\
\calperiod{04} & \calperiod{05} & \calperiod{06} \\[1ex]

% third row: week day and month
\calrow{July} & \calrow{August} & \calrow{September} \\
\calperiod{07} & \calperiod{08} & \calperiod{09} \\[1ex]


% forth row: calendar
\calrow{October} & \calrow{November} & \calrow{December} \\
\calperiod{10} & \calperiod{11} & \calperiod{12} \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can we make each block 7 rows? In that case, printing 2018 and 2019 sizde by side will give same sizes of pages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get a different year, one could simply use `\year=2017`. But if this was undesirable then a `\currentyear` macro could be used (optionally as a default argument to the `\calperiod` macro).

To get the year typeset at the corners of the matrix, I have used `append after command`. This requires that `\currentyear` be set outside the scope of the matrix. Also a bit of extra space is required at the bottom of the matrix to avoid some overlapping with the year labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calendar}

\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{holiday}{black!50}
\newcommand{\calrow}[1]{\node[anchor=base east](Mon){M};
\node[base right=of Mon](Tue){T}; \node[base right=of Tue](Wed){W};
\node[base right=of Wed](Thu){T}; \node[base right=of Thu](Fri){F};
\node[base right=of Fri](Sat){S}; \node[base right=of Sat](Sun){S};
\node[darkgreen, above=of Thu]{\textbf{#1}};}

\newcommand{\calperiod}[2][\currentyear]{%
  \calendar[dates=\currentyear-#2-01 to \currentyear-#2-last]
    if (Sunday) [holiday] \holidays;}
\edef\currentyear{\the\year}
\newcommand{\holidays}{% holidays in Italy
if (equals=01-01) [holiday]%
if (equals=01-06) [holiday]%
if (equals=04-04) [holiday]%
if (equals=04-05) [holiday]%
if (equals=04-25) [holiday]%
if (equals=05-01) [holiday]%
if (equals=05-01) [holiday]%
if (equals=06-02) [holiday]%
if (equals=08-15) [holiday]%
if (equals=11-01) [holiday]%
if (equals=12-08) [holiday]%
if (equals=12-25) [holiday]%
if (equals=12-26) [holiday]%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list},
year label/.style={
  fill=white,text=darkgreen,font=\bfseries\Large
}, current year/.store in=\currentyear,
current year=2017]
\matrix[%
row 1/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},%
row 3/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
row 5/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
row 7/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
column sep=1ex,%
draw=darkgreen,thick,rounded corners=5pt,%
append after command={ 
  \pgfextra{\edef\matrixname{\tikzlastnode}}
  node [year label/.try, right=1ex of \matrixname.south west] {\currentyear}
  node [year label/.try, right=1ex of \matrixname.north west] {\currentyear}
  node [year label/.try, left=1ex of \matrixname.south east] {\currentyear}
  node [year label/.try, left=1ex of \matrixname.north east] {\currentyear}
}
]{%

% first row: week day and month
\calrow{January} & \calrow{February} & \calrow{March} \\
\calperiod{01} & \calperiod{02} & \calperiod{03} \\[1ex]

% second row: calendar
\calrow{April} & \calrow{May} & \calrow{June} \\
\calperiod{04} & \calperiod{05} & \calperiod{06} \\[1ex]

% third row: week day and month
\calrow{July} & \calrow{August} & \calrow{September} \\
\calperiod{07} & \calperiod{08} & \calperiod{09} \\[1ex]

% forth row: calendar
\calrow{October} & \calrow{November} & \calrow{December} \\
\calperiod{10} & \calperiod{11} & \calperiod{12} \\[1ex]\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can we strike passing days?

Answer (score 5):

The border starts from north east corner in the anti clock wise direction. The horizontal distance is 2 parts and the vertical 3 parts. So the 2 comes at north west, 5 comes at south west, 7 comes at south east. Now you can add more decorations at each corners.

```
\documentclass[border=4.9mm, multi={tikzpicture}]{standalone}
%\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,tmargin=4.5cm,centering,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%%in preamble:
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calendar}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\newcommand{\calrow}[1]{\node[anchor=base east](Mon){M};
\node[base right=of Mon](Tue){T}; \node[base right=of Tue](Wed){W};
\node[base right=of Wed](Thu){T}; \node[base right=of Thu](Fri){F};
\node[base right=of Fri](Sat){S}; \node[base right=of Sat](Sun){S};
\node[darkgreen,above=of Thu]{\textbf{#1}};}

\newcommand{\calperiod}[1]{\calendar[dates=\the\year-#1-01 to \the\year-#1-last]
if(Sunday) [black!50] \holidays;}

\newcommand{\holidays}{% holidays in Italy
if (equals=01-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=01-06) [black!50]%
if (equals=04-04) [black!50]%
if (equals=04-05) [black!50]%
if (equals=04-25) [black!50]%
if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=06-02) [black!50]%
if (equals=08-15) [black!50]%
if (equals=11-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=12-08) [black!50]%
if (equals=12-25) [black!50]%
if (equals=12-26) [black!50]%
}

\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}

\begin{document}
%%in document:
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list}]
\sffamily
\matrix[%
row 1/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},%
row 3/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
row 5/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
row 7/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
column sep=1ex,%
draw=darkgreen,thick,rounded corners=5pt,%
postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.2 with
{\node[fill=white,text=darkgreen,font={\bfseries\Large}] (year) {\the\year};}
}},
postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.51 with
{\node[fill=white,text=darkgreen,font={\bfseries\Large}] (year) {\the\year};}
}},
postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.7 with
{\node[fill=white,text=darkgreen,font={\bfseries\Large}] (year) {\the\year};}
}},
postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.01 with
{\node[fill=white,text=darkgreen,font={\bfseries\Large}] (year) {\the\year};}
}},
% year on frame: decorations.markings library
]{%

% first row: week day and month
\calrow{January} & \calrow{February} & \calrow{March} \\
\calperiod{01} & \calperiod{02} & \calperiod{03} \\[1ex]

% second row: calendar
\calrow{April} & \calrow{May} & \calrow{June} \\
\calperiod{04} & \calperiod{05} & \calperiod{06} \\[1ex]

% third row: week day and month
\calrow{July} & \calrow{August} & \calrow{September} \\
\calperiod{07} & \calperiod{08} & \calperiod{09} \\[1ex]


% forth row: calendar
\calrow{October} & \calrow{November} & \calrow{December} \\
\calperiod{10} & \calperiod{11} & \calperiod{12} \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't follow the `how to change the year to custom year` part properly.